# How to insert a text into before all magento notification messages in magento 2 with plugin?

Tags: magento2, plugin, after-plugin

I'm new Magento. Can someone tell me how to insert a text into before all system messages of Magento 2 with a plugin. When I do anything, I get the message.Ex :login, create account, add to cart,...[image]